# How to open another activity with a button on the action bar?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-actionbar

in my action bar I put a button that goes to another activity but the code that does not work I'm testing and the application fails.

This is the code file menu (main.xml):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.hello.turidf.MainActivity" >


<item
    android:id="@+id/action_about"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_about"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:onClick="enterInfo" />

</menu>
```

And this is the code of the Java file (MainActivity.java):

```
package com.hello.turidf;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.Intent;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_about) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, InfoActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace. "does not work" doesn't give us enough information to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct. I guess isn't working because you use the line in your menu.xml

```
android:onClick="enterInfo"
```

The program is expecting that you has a enterInfo method that is called when you click the button, and the OnOptionsItemSelected doesn't get called. Just take out the line and try.

Comment: Thanks, this solution is correct. Greetings from Mexico :)